# Graphql mutation return value

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

The graphql mutation below returns an `Account` type on success:

```js
@Mutation(() => Account)
async updateAccount(
  @Arg('accountIdentifier', () => String) accountIdentifier: string,
  @Arg('input', () => AccountUpdateInput) input: AccountUpdateInput
) {
  await Account.update({ accountIdentifier }, input)
  return Account.findOne({ accountIdentifier })
}
```

To execute this mutation one can use the following:

```
mutation {
  updateAccount(
    accountIdentifier: "06760b98-9a9b-4686-961c-051d6b01581f", 
    input: {
      name: "mark"
    }) {
    accountIdentifier
    email
  }
}
```

However, using this same mutation without specifying a return value results in an error. I was wondering if it's possible to execute the above mutation or the below mutation (without return value specified) and  at the same time have the mutation executed correctly?

```
mutation {
  updateAccount(
    accountIdentifier: "06760b98-9a9b-4686-961c-051d6b01581f", 
    input: {
      name: "mark"
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: If the return type of a field is an object type, you must specify a selection set of at least one child field when requesting the field.

Comment: Thank you, I've noticed that. But I was wondering if this is possible: "If the user provided a field from Account as return value, return the Account fields needed. If the user didn't define a return value simply return Boolean true on success"

Comment: You'd have to utilize a custom scalar (like a JSON scalar) and then implement that logic inside your resolver, using the info parameter to determine whether a selection set was provided.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into that thank you.